# how to pass data from a button which opens a model and delete the data when ok button is pressed. the button and modal are in two different pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to pass data on click of a button to model using href or using data-id where both didnt work.

1. href to the controller along with the id which has to be passed to modal page
2. using data-id and ajax call

Controller:

```
public function delete_get_id($pcode){
    if($this->input->post('deleteproj'))
    {
        $this->project_model->delete_project($pcode);
    }
}
```

view page where button is present:

```html
<button id="deletebutton" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deletemodal" data-id="<?php echo $row->project_code;?>" ><span class = "fa fa-trash-o"></span> Delete</button>
```

view page of modal:

```html
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" id="deletemodal">
......
......
<button class="btn btn-danger btn delete" id ="deleteproject" <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-trash "></span>Delete</button>
```

ajax:

```
$('#deletebutton').click(function(){
    var pcode = $(this).data('id');
    $('#deleteproject').data('id', pcode); 
});

$('#deleteproject').click(function(){
    var pcode = $(this).data('id');

    $('#deletemodal').modal('hide');
        $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
        $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "index.php/project/delete_get_id/"+ pcode,
            data: {
             pcode: $pcode,
             deleteproj: 1,
            },
            success: function (data) {
            $("#deletemodal").modal('hide');
            showproject();
        }
    });
});

function showproject(){
    //which opens another page on success
}
```

Error:

> Undefined variable pcode (as the value pcode is not received)

Expected result:
Since I'm deleting data from a table, I have to get the pcode of respective row and delete data after the modal pops up.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. On the "deletebutton", you're missing the closing `"` after you're echoing the project code. And on the "deleteproject" button, You're not closing the `<button>` opening tag before writing the `<span>`.

Comment: Also, you're not passing the data correctly in your ajax. First off, you're using the variable `$pcode`, which is undefined. You should also either pass the data as a json object `data: {param1: val1, param2: val2}` or in the query string format: `data: "param1=val1&param2=var2"`. There's too many issues here. Please make sure that the HTML is valid and that you use the functions/methods in the correct way (look at the jQuery manual).